# Get transactions between a wallet and a token

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions, wallet, address

Is there a way to fetch transactions that involve a certain wallet AND token address?

Meaning, any transaction(sale, mint, etc) that occurred between the two.

I've tried filtering manually using `@solana/web3.js`' `getSignaturesForAddress` paired with `getParsedTransactions` - However, it seems like too much fetching and data manipulation to get to the desired result.

Perhaps there's a 3rd party API that offers a similar/more convenient endpoint for this use case? Or a simpler way to get this data?

Thank you.

Comment: Without using a 3rd party API, you already have the right answer, and you'll have to sift through the transactions

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSignaturesForAddress` on the token [ATA](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/associated-token-account).

```
import { getAssociatedTokenAddressSync } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';

async function getTxsByToken(conn: Connection, mint: PublicKey, wallet: PublicKey) {
    const ata = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(mint, wallet);
    return conn.getSignaturesForAddress(ata);
}
```

Note that there might be other token accounts (non ATA) that you would miss with this approach.

Comment: I thought of using accounts, but then a different issue arises, where any account that was closed will not be queried. So looking for a solution that is transaction based rather than account based. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: this one might work then, it has a `mint` filter: https://docs.solana.fm/reference/get_account_transactions_from_master